# build a c program like portable program with libraries

Tags: c, static-libraries, cross-compiling, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to create a c program that work in multi linux os (ex ubuntu 16 64bit, centos 6 64bit, ubuntu 12 64bit,..)  without installing the dependencies.
for example I'm using the  libgcrypt.so.20 library in my program
I need a way to compile my program and import all necessary library from lib folder, so in the other host i just copy my compiled program and my lib folder that contains all my .so library 
because I don't have privilege to install libgcrypt in the other host.
so if this is possible ?

Comment: You can't just run stuff compiled for OS x on OS y even if your code is cross platform.

Comment: The normal way to avoid problems with shared library versions is to use static libraries.  Whether that'll be good enough for you is open to debate.  And getting static libraries of all dependencies may be fraught and error prone.  You probably need to use the local C library rather than an imported one, for example.  If you must use shared libraries, you'll need to locate them near where your executable is installed (e.g. in $HOME/lib if you install the executable in $HOME/bin) and set appropriate environment variables to appropriate values.

Comment: You might end up running a shell script to set the environment to the appropriate values before running the actual executable.  That is, $HOME/bin might contain a shell script that ends up with `exec ${YOUR_REAL_PROGRAM} "$@"` where the variable `YOUR_REAL_PROGRAM` knows where your binary is, and the preceding code sets the environment correctly.